# How to customize oracle standard bpm worklist region

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-adf, oracle-soa, oracle-bpm-suite

**Background:**

I have to display the Oracle BPEM worklist tasks for the currently loggedin user from two different sources (*OIM worklist and SOA worklist*). What is the simplest way to do it.

Oracle provides its own worklist application to display the available worklists for the user. But the issue with that approach is that the user is displayed with a generic (from Oracle) webpage and it gives too many options to the user.

**My requirements:**

Show a simple data table with the list of available tasks for the user from all the available sources. The user can then click on a task and then view the further details associated with the task.

**My approach so far:**

1) Use the ready made 'worklist' region provided by Oracle

[image]

2) Created two worklist connections to source the tasks from different locations

[image]

3) Included the ready made(from oracle) worklist region into my page

[image]

4) The rendered page looks like this

[image]

**My questions:**

1) How can I customize the display of items displayed to me by the standard oracle worklist region ?.

2) How can I show all the available items as a single list (at the moment it doesn't display all in one go, it shows only the first 25 records..then user has to click on a more link)

3) Is there any other simple ways to display all the tasks available to the user ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make `MDS Customization` on Oracle's Worklist task flow, however it only allows customization on the view.

Although declarative approach is offered for ADF developers, Oracle developers mostly manages data in backing beans instead of data bindings. Thus MDS Customization is not a solution for your requirement.

If you try to customize the task flow, you will see that java classes are compiled and no source code is publicly available.

One like me can go further and can decompile java classes, change whatever needed and deploy to the Weblogic. Than if you enforce the managed server's ClassLoader to load your class, it will work.

To the best of my knowledge there is no other solution offered by Oracle for this task.